# How to fetch with the type string in SOLR?

Tags: solr

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

```
String query = MODULE:(\"42\" OR \"146\" OR \"47\");
```

SOLR SEARCH ENGINE

on search in the fq:

```
childId: * 42 *
```

It is currently listing the details with child ids 42, 142 and 442
(screen shot attached)

Expected: Restrict the query using regular expression so that it will list out the details which have child id as 42 in it.

In the `schema.xml`:

```
<field name="rptChildIds" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing your question - what is the content of the field, what are you querying and what are you expecting to get back? Since your query lists all three module ids, all three would be returned. If the field type is `string` (and you did not change it AFTER indexing content into it) and you only search for `46` - only fields with the exact content `46` would be returned.

Comment: In the schema.xml i have field as <field name="rptChildIds" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> since its of type string it will consider everything and 1 search input . Child Ids can be ("45","145" "46") , when i search for 45 i should be getting only details related to Child Id 45 , currently, i am parsing in in my back-end code and forming the query in such a way that whatever is entered in search box it should give out the specific details which are related to id 45

Comment: I need a query with some regex that when i search for the *45* the filter query it should list out the details which have child id 45 in it

Comment: Is the _actual_ content of the field `("45","145" "46")`? What is the verbatim text stored in the field? If that's the case - searching for `field:*\"45\"*` might work (i.e. explicitly including the quotes in the search query, instead of wrapping it).

Comment: As suggested tried  field:*\"45\"* {
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "fq":"rptChildIds:*\\\"45\\\"*",
      "_":"1589969836577"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}